# How to enter dashes in \hyphenation?

Tags: pdftex, punctuation, hyphenation

I have an extra file for all my hyphenations.

Alas, the command `\hyphenation` does not understand the `=` notation for "dash that stays after hyphenation here".

Is there any way to get `\hyphenation` to handle that?

Here is an except from my file:

```
\hyphenation{Hash-ta-bel-le}
\hyphenation{Hash-ta-bel-len}
\hyphenation{De-fault-ope-ra-tio-nen}
\hyphenation{De-fault-ope-ra-tion}
\hyphenation{Sig-nal=und=Slot=Kon-zept}
\hyphenation{Lauf-zeit-in-for-ma-tio-nen}
\hyphenation{Lauf-zeit-in-for-ma-tion}
\hyphenation{Sig-nal=Slot=Ver-bin-dung}
\hyphenation{Sig-nal=Slot=Ver-bin-dungen}
\hyphenation{De-fault=But-ton}
```

All lines with an `=` produce an error like this

```
(./latex/trennung.tex
! Not a letter.
l.81 \hyphenation{Sig-nal=
                          und=Slot=Kon-zept}
?
```

Comment: `\hyphenation` takes as argument strings separated by spaces; the strings consist of letters and hyphens. With LuaTeX the syntax is extended, but not with classical `pdflatex`, allowing something like `sig-nal{-}{}{-}und{-}{}{-}Slot{-}{}{-}Kon-zept`

Comment: @egreg Really? How sad. No pdflatex alternative?